# Adding columns from every other row in a pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

In the picture, [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7zXQh.png), you can see the start of my data frame. I would like to make two new columns that consist of the values (confirmed_cases and deaths) and to get rid of the 'Type' column. Essentially I want there to be one row of data for each county and to have a confirmed_cases and death column added using the values from the data already. I tried the code below but obviously the length of values does not match the length of index.

Any suggestions?

```html
apidata['Confirmed_Cases'] = apidata['values'].iloc[::2].values
apidata['Deaths'] = apidata['values'].iloc[1::2].values
```

(Sorry about the link to the photo, I am too new to the site to be able to just include the photo in the post)

Maybe if there's a way to double how many times each value is posted in the new column? So first five deaths would be [5, 5, 26, 26, 0] and then I can just delete every other row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up figuring it out, by creating a second dataframe that deleted half of the rows (every other one) from the first dataframe and then adding the values from the original dataframe into the new one.

```html
apidata2 = apidata.iloc[::2]
apidata2['Confirmed_Cases'] = apidata['values'].iloc[::2].values
apidata2['Deaths'] = apidata['values'].iloc[1::2].values
apidata2.head()
```

[Finished output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4TzaC.png)